# Perl : Capturing data from recursive calls

Tags: perl, recursion

I have written a function to take in a Array of Arrays and print it in something like an XML format without the tags. The function works when I keep the Buffer string variable global. But since I want to avoid bad practices, I was trying to pass it to the function. I am providing a MWE which shows all the cases.

Input :

```
( "main",
         ["fred", 
                 ["barney"] ],
         ["george", 
                   ["jane", 
                           ["elroy"] ] ],
         ["homer", 
                  ["marge", 
                           ["bart"] ] ]
);
```

This basically represents a tree structure if I may call it that. It stores the hierarchy of few folders.

Correct Output for me -

```
name my_gen_XML;


    name "main";
        name "fred";
            name "barney";
            name
        name
        name "george";
            name "jane";
                name "elroy";
                name
            name
        name
        name "homer";
            name "marge";
                name "bart";
                name
            name
        name
```

Wrong output -

```
name my_gen_XML;


    name "main";
        name
        name
        name
```

In the code snippet below, I've mentioned 2 cases called working and non-working. The working case produces the correct output. The non-working case provides the wrong output.

My part of the code -

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Data::Dumper;        
    my @test = ( "main",
                        ["fred", 
                                ["barney"] ],
                        ["george", 
                                ["jane", 
                                        ["elroy"] ] ],
                        ["homer", 
                                ["marge", 
                                        ["bart"] ] ]
                );
    my $testRef = \@test;
    ## Working - Case
    #my $strBuffer;

    my $final = constructTree($testRef,"    name");

    print "$final \n";

    # Name : constructTree
    sub constructTree {
        my ($test, $indentStr) = @_;
        my $strBuffer = "";
        ## Non-Working Case
        $strBuffer = populateTree($test, $indentStr, $strBuffer);
        ## Working - Case
        #$strBuffer = populateTree($test, $indentStr);

        $strBuffer = "name my_gen_XML;\n\n\n".$strBuffer;

        return $strBuffer;
    }

    # Name : populateTree
    sub populateTree {
        ## Non-Working Case
        my ($array, $indentText, $strBuffer) = @_;
        ## Working - Case
        #my ($array, $indentText) = @_;
        my @list = @$array;

        $strBuffer .= "    $indentText \"$list[0]\";\n";
        $indentText = "    $indentText";
        shift(@list);

        foreach my $child ( @list ) {
            ## Non-Working Case
            populateTree(\@$child, $indentText, $strBuffer);
            ## Working - Case
            #populateTree(\@$child, $indentText);
            $strBuffer .= "    $indentText\n";
        }
        return $strBuffer;
    }
```

I tried using state variables for `$strBuffer` but to of no avail. I also tried capturing the output of the recursive function but that duplicated my case. Also tried using a temporary variable but didn't help my case either.

I would like to know how to get the "correct output" using "non-working code". I thought it is a simple fix but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try to pass around a reference to the `$strBuffer` and not the string variable itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example passing `$strBuffer` as a reference:

```
sub constructTree {
    my ($test, $indentStr) = @_;

    my $strBuffer = "";
    my $strBufferRef = populateTree($test, $indentStr, \$strBuffer);
    $strBuffer = "name my_gen_XML;\n\n\n".$$strBufferRef;
    return $strBuffer;
}

sub populateTree {
    my ($array, $indentText, $strBuffer) = @_;

    my $item = shift @$array;
    $$strBuffer .= "    $indentText \"$item\";\n";
    my $newIndentText = "    $indentText";

    foreach my $child ( @$array ) {
        populateTree($child, $newIndentText, $strBuffer);
        $$strBuffer .= "    $indentText\n";
    }
    return $strBuffer;
}
```

**Output**:

```
name my_gen_XML;


        name "main";
            name "fred";
                name "barney";
            name
        name
            name "george";
                name "jane";
                    name "elroy";
                name
            name
        name
            name "homer";
                name "marge";
                    name "bart";
                name
            name
        name
```

Comment: Yes. That worked. Just tried it out. So basically the scope of reference the variable remains during the recursive calls but the variable doesn't? Is that where I was missing it? If that's case state should have helped too right?

Comment: @SDCode Yes for each recursive call you passed a new copy of `$strBuffer` (instead of a reference) and that copy was never returned to the caller. That is the purpose of the reference, any modifications in the called sub will be visible in the caller's variable (through the reference)

Comment: Okay. That makes more sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The statement `my ($foo, $bar) = @_;` copies each element of @_ to those variables. This means that if one of those elements is a string, its value is copied to the variable, and changing that variable does not change the original.

Aside from passing a scalar reference to the string instead of the string itself, as covered in the other answer (which I recommend), you can use the aliasing behavior of Perl, but this is generally not well-known behavior so it may be less clear to the reader (comments probably useful here).

The elements of `@_` itself are not copies, but aliases, so you can modify the original value by accessing that element directly instead of copying it to another variable, but this is not very readable.

```
sub populateTree {
    my ($array, $indentText) = @_;

    my $item = shift @$array;
    $_[2] .= "    $indentText \"$item\";\n";
    my $newIndentText = "    $indentText";

    foreach my $child ( @$array ) {
        populateTree($child, $newIndentText, $_[2]);
        $_[2] .= "    $indentText\n";
    }
    return $_[2];
}
```

On very recent versions of Perl (5.22+) there is an experimental feature called [refaliasing](https://perldoc.pl/feature#The-'refaliasing'-feature) which allows you to easily create your own aliased variable.

```
use experimental 'refaliasing';

sub populateTree {
    my ($array, $indentText) = @_;
    \my $strBuffer = \$_[2];

    my $item = shift @$array;
    $strBuffer .= "    $indentText \"$item\";\n";
    my $newIndentText = "    $indentText";

    foreach my $child ( @$array ) {
        populateTree($child, $newIndentText, $strBuffer);
        $strBuffer .= "    $indentText\n";
    }
    return $strBuffer;
}
```

The CPAN module [Data::Alias](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias) allows you to do this on any version of Perl.

```
use Data::Alias;

sub populateTree {
    my ($array, $indentText) = @_;
    alias my $strBuffer = $_[2];

    my $item = shift @$array;
    $strBuffer .= "    $indentText \"$item\";\n";
    my $newIndentText = "    $indentText";

    foreach my $child ( @$array ) {
        populateTree($child, $newIndentText, $strBuffer);
        $strBuffer .= "    $indentText\n";
    }
    return $strBuffer;
}
```

And finally, you can (ab)use the aliasing behavior of the [foreach loop](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops) to make your own alias in a slightly odder (but more compatible) way.

```
sub populateTree {
    my ($array, $indentText) = @_;
    foreach my $strBuffer ($_[2]) {
        my $item = shift @$array;
        $strBuffer .= "    $indentText \"$item\";\n";
        my $newIndentText = "    $indentText";

        foreach my $child ( @$array ) {
            populateTree($child, $newIndentText, $strBuffer);
            $strBuffer .= "    $indentText\n";
        }
        return $strBuffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response and for making me learn new way(s) of doing the same. I wanted to ask about your final method(aliasing behaviour of foreach loop), won't it add an extra for loop and increase the execution time for the same.

Comment: Not noticeably: it loops over one item, so it's the same as running a regular code block, just with the variable aliased. (Fun fact: [bare blocks](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Basic-BLOCKs) are actually loops that run once, too.)

Comment: Woah. Interesting! Thanks for sharing that link!